# Postgresql insert in PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

All my scripts are written in pdo-mysql . Now i am migrating to posgresql. I have been stuck in an insert query.

```
CREATE TABLE bus_spot
(
    bus_id integer NOT NULL,
    spot_loc_id integer NOT NULL,
    bus_dir_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

php query used

```
$Bus_Id = 579;
$Bus_Dir_Id = 3;
$User_Loc_Id = 465;

$ISp_Res = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO bus_spot(bus_id, bus_dir_id, spot_loc_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$ISp_Res->execute(array($Bus_Id, $Bus_Dir_Id, $User_Loc_Id));
```

I am getting the following error when trying to insert this row

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: \"\""}

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like Postgres is being a bit picky about the input format for the integers. Try binding the parameters using the appropriate type instead of passing them to the `execute()` method which implicitly uses strings

```
$ISp_Res = $pdo->prepare(...);

$ISp_Res->bindParam(1, $Bus_Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ISp_Res->bindParam(2, $Bus_Dir_Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ISp_Res->bindParam(3, $User_Loc_Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$ISp_Res->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Phil.. It wrked :).. I again got stuck in another line.. This is the code I used to get  last insert id $Ins_Id = $pdo->lastInsertId(`Bus_Spot_Id`) in PHP... But it is not working in postgresql..

Comment: @Dileep: PostgreSQL doesn't really have a concept of "last insert ID".  (Even if it did, specifying the ID when you insert would keep an ID from getting auto-created.)  But if your ID field is of type `serial` or `bigserial`, then the most reliable solution is to use the sequence that is created as part of defining a serial field.  Get a new ID via `SELECT nextval('bus_spot_bus_id_seq')` (or something very similar), and use that as the ID when you `INSERT`.  (At which point you already have the ID, so you don't need to ask the server "what was the last ID you generated for me?".  :))

Comment: finally i got the insert id by using the "RETURNING bus_spot_id " in the insert query.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If that example is the actual code you're using, then your server is borked.  :P  Your example works just fine in my VM.

More likely is that one of the "integers" you're passing to the query is stringifying as an empty string.  That's the case for the constants `null` and `false`, and of course `''`.  PostgreSQL is stricter about conversions than MySQL is, and generally will throw an error rather than try to convert a string to an integer if it doesn't look like one.

See what happens if you pass `intval($Bus_Id)` etc instead of passing the values as is.  If that works, then your values are broken, and you need to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks Chao.. I used Phil answer and it wrked

Comment: @Dileep: Then take a closer look at what you're actually passing, vs what you *think* you're passing.  If forcing the type "works" here, then it's probably by accident -- at least one of your values probably isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 placeholders in your `VALUES`

```
VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

But your table/array is only 3

```
array($Bus_Id,$Bus_Dir_Id,$User_Loc_Id)
```

Remove 1 placeholder

```
VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Comment: I have edited it, it was a mistake while copying. Even after removing 1 place holder i am getting the same error. I guess this is not the right way in passing integers